# Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements and Access denied for the root user

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install the PHPMyAdmin but I am getting some errors.

I have referred this link for [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I have tried the below command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-zip php-gd php-json php-curl
```

Let me share them one by one here

1. Every time I am getting the below password error

> Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Then I select **abort** and clicked on **OK**

[image]

I have follow the same steps that is on the reference link

2. I am not able to login it using

   ```
   sudo mysql

   mysql -u root -p
   ```

but getting below error

> root@41:~# sudo MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have referred this link but I am still getting an error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y

I also tried to stop my SQL and check in safe mode but still got the same error.

I have deleted PHPMyAdmin more than 2-3 times, deleted the MySQL server, and rebuild the server again but still got the same error...

any idea what I am doing wrong here? or any steps that can help me to solve this issue?

MySQL-server is already the newest version (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145802/discussion-on-question-by-user9437856-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.